# CakePHP: Administrator model that can create other models

Tags: cakephp

I have the following models: `Students, Teachers, Administrator`

What I want to do is have an Admin menu, where I can list all the students and teachers, create new, and edit them too.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Import the model into the admin controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anh says, the most straight forward way is to have `admin_` actions in the student and teacher controllers respectively. You can access any model from any controller. If you want to list teachers in the students controller or vice versa, you can do so.
By default, a controller only imports the model of the same name. If that model is associated with other models, you can access the other models through the association like `$this->Student->Teacher`.
If you're going to do this often in a controller, simply load the necessary models directly into the controller using the `$uses` property:

```
class StudentsController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Student', 'Teacher');
}
```

Now you have both models available directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use prefix routing. In the teacher controller, create actions for admin (admin_index(), admin_add(), etc.) that can add/edit/remove records of teachers. Same for student controller.

Edit: the controller is where you can manipulate a particular model (and related models). If you want both students and teachers on a certain page, are these 2 models related to each other? Wait, aren't they both Users of the website? So what you want is: Admins can CRUD Users, right? So you can have all users listed in admin/users/index page (What I want to show here is: a problem can sometimes lead to a new db design, because you realize what you actually want these models to be).

Either that, or you can make a quick and dirty fix by either: loadModel in a controller of your choice, or use $uses, or make an arbitrary relationship between Teacher and Student.

Comment: what if i want to have a list of students and teachers on the admin's index action? I guess I could load them with ajax?

Comment: Have a look at this link, will explain how to load multiple models methods into a single controller - http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/